# How to assign threads to per request actors in Akka

Tags: multithreading, scala, akka, scala-2.10

I have a consistent hashing router (scala/akka) that assigns a particular message type `a` to a particular set of per-request actors `A`, and a message type`b` to a particular set of per-request actors `B`... etc. Question is: how do I appropriate the set of actors `A` to a its own thread `A`, and the set of actors `B` to its own thread `B`?

The hope is that actor set `A` does not block actor set `B` and `B` does not block `A`. Sadly, my Akka dispatcher experience lacks, as does my multithreading experience. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure a dispatcher for the actors of type A, and B.

See http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/dispatchers.html for full details, but one example of doing this is to do it by specifying a specific Dispatch when creating your actors.  Simply append `withDispatcher("dispatcher-actortype-A")` to the your actor's Props object, then in your akka configuration file, add:

```
dispatcher-actortype-A {
  # Dispatcher is the name of the event-based dispatcher
  type = Dispatcher
  # What kind of ExecutionService to use
  executor = "thread-pool-executor"
  # Configuration for the thread pool
  thread-pool-executor {
    # minimum number of threads to cap factor-based core number to
    core-pool-size-min = 2
    # No of core threads ... ceil(available processors * factor)
    core-pool-size-factor = 2.0
    # maximum number of threads to cap factor-based number to
    core-pool-size-max = 10
  }
  # Process 100 messages before moving to the next actor
  throughput = 100
}
```

Obviously, you'll want to create a dispatcher for the B actors too.

Comment: Thanks. Let's say the sets of actors `A` and `B` were broken down into further subsets on-request, say `Aa`, `Ab`, `Ac`, etc. I suppose there would be no way to define dispatchers on request to prevent `Aa` from blocking `Ab`, etc.?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I follow.  Are you suggesting that Aa, Ab etc... are each new Actor types?  If so, then you'd want to create a dispatcher for Aa, Ab etc...  If that's not what you meant, that I'm afraid I don't understand the question - perhaps you could elaborate?

Comment: Sorry. I guess my point is, if I could have an unbounded number of per-request actors, then my configuration file would need to be an infinitely long list of dispatchers. Which seems impractical.